# How do i dump the contents of an SQLite database without using the command line, but in Perl code?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

For regression testing i need to dump the entire contents of an SQLite database into a text file. But all references to that sort of activity only lead to guides using the sqlite executable. Is there a way in Perl to do this without the executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard DBI methods for querying schema. DBD::SQLite manpage says:

> See also to the DBI documentation for
>   the details of other common methods.
>
> table_info
>
> ```
>  $sth = $dbh->table_info(undef, $schema, $table, $type, \%attr);
> ```
>
> Returns all tables and schemas
>   (databases) as specified in
>   "table_info" in DBI.  The schema and
>   table arguments will do a "LIKE"
>   search. You can    specify an ESCAPE
>   character by including an ’Escape’
>   attribute in \%attr. The $type
>   argument accepts a comma separated
>   list of the following types
>   ’TABLE’, ’VIEW’, ’LOCAL TEMPORARY’ and
>   ’SYSTEM TABLE’ (by default all are
>   returned).  Note that a statement
>   handle is returned, and not a direct
>   list of tables.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to steal the `.dump` implementation from the sqlite program's source code.